# I want to replace values in vector "Dist_AU25M", but not change in the data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

```
AU_PROP <- read_csv2("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datatto/AU25-de-Mayo/master/AU_F_Properati_v2.csv") 
names(AU_PROP)

AU_PROP1<- select(AU_PROP, base, operation, property_t, place_name, Latitud, Longitud, currency_, price_usd, Total_m2, usd_m2, AU_Unidad, Tramo,    sector, km2, Dist_AU25M,Franja) %>% 
  filter(usd_m2>1500&usd_m2<5000)%>% 
  replace("Dist_AU25M"==50,25)
```

Comment: Have you read the docs for `replace`? Your arguments don't match what the docs spell out

Answer (score 1):

We can use that within `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
AU_PROP1 <- select(AU_PROP, base, operation, property_t, place_name, Latitud, 
     Longitud, currency_, price_usd, Total_m2, 
     usd_m2, AU_Unidad, Tramo, sector, km2, Dist_AU25M,Franja) %>% 
          filter(usd_m2 > 1500, usd_m2 < 5000)%>% 
          mutate(Dist_AU25M =  replace(Dist_AU25M, Dist_AU25M==50, 25))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, If i want to replace several values at once, whatch code  could i use? I tried this: AU_PROP1<- select(AU_PROP, base, operation, property_t, place_name, Latitud, Longitud, currency_, price_usd, Total_m2, usd_m2, AU_Unidad, Tramo, sector, km2, Dist_AU25M,Franja) %>% filter(usd_m2>1500&usd_m2<5000)%>% mutate(Dist_AU25M=  replace(Dist_AU25M, Dist_AU25M==25| Dist_AU25M==50,100) %>%mutate(Dist_AU25M=  replace(Dist_AU25M, Dist_AU25M==600|Dist_AU25M==700|Dist_AU25M==800|Dist_AU25M==900,1000))

Comment: @AugustoTovarNumpaque  IN that case, replace the `==` with `%in%` and pass a vector of values `Dist_AU25M %in% c(50, 75, 125)`